# JSColor onChange Event saying function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function, jscolor

I'm trying to use the onChange event for JSColor to call a function but every time it fires, I get an error stating that the function is not defined. My code is below.

```
export class NavBar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    setLinkTextColor(color)  {
        console.log("hello")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sideOptionContainer">
                <button className="jscolor" id="jscolor1" data-jscolor="{valueElement:'#val3', onChange: 'setLinkTextColor(this)'}">,</button>
                <input id="val3" value="rgba(255,160,0)" name="color3" type="hidden"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I've tried moving the function inside of `render()` as `function setLinkTextColor(color)`, thinking that maybe it had something to do with the scope, but I get the same exact error.

Edit: I've tried the following fix, removing the string from onChange and creating a global function -

```
export class NavBar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sideOptionContainer">
                <button className="jscolor" id="jscolor1" data-jscolor="{valueElement:'#val3', onChange: setLinkTextColor(this)}">,</button>
                <input id="val3" value="rgba(255,160,0)" name="color3" type="hidden"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function setLinkTextColor(color)  {
    console.log("hello")
}
```

Although I'm not getting any errors anymore, the onChange event is no longer firing when I change the color input.

Comment: The onchange should not be a string.

Comment: @epascarello I tried that and now it seems as though the function is never called. I edited my post to show what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is React, you need to bind your `setLinkTextColor` function in the constructor:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.setLinkTextColor = this.setLinkTextColor.bind(this);
}
```

Then, in your JSColor config, you can't use a string, because JSColor can't access your function inside of your class. Instead, do this:

```js
render() {
    const jsColorConfig = {
        valueElement: '#val3', 
        onChange: this.setLinkTextColor
    };

    return (
        <div className="sideOptionContainer">
            <button className="jscolor" id="jscolor1" data-jscolor={jsColorConfig}>,</button>
            <input id="val3" value="rgba(255,160,0)" name="color3" type="hidden"/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried your solution and while it did get rid of the "undefined function" error, now it seems like the function is never called. I edited my post to reflect what I did.

Comment: Now I get an error saying that the jscolor options are invalid. I posted the full error with my fix in my edited post.

Comment: What happens if you change `data-jscolor={jsColorConfig}` to `data-jscolor={JSON.stringify(jsColorConfig)}`?

Comment: Hmm, it takes care of all the errors but now the onChange event isn't firing at all when I change colors.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought... Looks like your function can't live inside your class, and needs to be a global function, then you can go back to using it with a string.

Comment: JSColor likely wasn't built with React (or rather, modern standards) in-mind.

Comment: I tried making the function global, using both the config and the string for the onChange event, with and without quotation marks, but to no avail. I'm starting to think this just might not be possible with React, sadly.

Comment: @SterlingVelazquez or, you could find a React color picker ;)

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the help.